# [ANSWERED]Is $\{n, n^{2} n^{3}\}$ a group under multiplication modulo $m = n + n^{2} + n^{3}$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

My number theory has been lacking, so i decided to practice it a bit. I have gotten better in the sense that i can figure out where to begin approaching a problem, but i am having trouble seeing the goal and the starting place in this one.

I tried $\{2, 4, 8\}$ modulo $14$ and this is a group with identity $8.$

Please tell me where or how you would begin approaching this problem, as i still want to try and tackle it myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are n^4, n^5, and n^6 modulo m? (use polynomial long divison)

Comment: Also, once you have an identity element, then you know from the general theory that the other two should be each others' inverses (if it is a group).

Comment: Excellent @DanUznanski thanks!

Comment: @user96454 If you've got it figured out, answer your own question.